# Integrating Office forms into .NET 4.8.1 web application

Tags: c#, .net, forms, ms-office, ms-forms

I'm developing an old web application using .NET Framework 4.8.1, and I need assistance with binding Office Forms.
Specifically, I want to integrate Office Forms surveys into my web app and ensure that the answers provided by users can be transferred to these forms seamlessly.

During my research, I came across the Office Forms API:

[https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/forms/{formid}/questions](https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/forms/%7Bformid%7D/questions)
[https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/forms/{formid}/responses](https://forms.office.com/formapi/api/forms/%7Bformid%7D/responses)
These endpoints allow fetching questions and responses respectively, leveraging Azure for authentication and data retrieval.

However, I'm uncertain about how to implement this integration seamlessly within my application.

Could someone please provide guidance or suggest resources on how to achieve this integration effectively? Any insights into utilizing Office Forms within a .NET web application and facilitating the transfer of user responses would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: The last version of .NET Framework was 4.8.*1*. So I'd first suggest you clear up what you're actually working with.